# Colored background with png image

Tags: html, css

I want to create a square white box with png image in it. I want png to follow background while the colour of box doesn't affect it.

Here is the sample of the output that I want:
[image]

As for now, the white background color couldn't work after I added background colour on div for image. I want the transparent space of png follow body background color.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2zh7vpe6/)

I've attached snippet too. Can someone help me to look into it? Thanks in advance!

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color:white;
}

.title {
  margin-top: auto;
  width: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="title">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/24/000000/print--v1.png"/>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider mask here:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
  min-height:100vh;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title {
  margin-top: auto;
  -webkit-mask:
    url(https://i.ibb.co/Zcvccd9/print-v1.png) center/contain no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  -webkit-mask-composite:destination-out;
          mask:
    url(https://i.ibb.co/Zcvccd9/print-v1.png) center/contain no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
          mask-composite:exclude;
  background: #fff;
}
.title img {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="title">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Zcvccd9/print-v1.png" >
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Step 1: Set position: absolute

Step 2: Set the width of the .title

Step 3: add a transparent color in between other colors in the linear background.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  background-color:white;
}

.title {
    margin-top: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 97vw;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #ffffff, #3456ab00, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
    animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="title">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/24/000000/print--v1.png"/>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: but why isn't the layer of printer is white? i want the side of printer is white, and the empty space of png is transparent?

Comment: Do you want the right side of the title to be white?The empty space of the png is already transparent.

Comment: I have updated my answer.Please run the snippet now.